# Function type signature in Haskell without using interpreter

Tags: haskell, types

For example I have following function:

```
g x y z = [x] ++ (g x (z:y) (x:z))
```

What does this code do? How can I find/guess type signature for this function?

Comment: As for figuring out the type signature, that's based on how the arguments are used inside the definition, and the types they need to have to be used as arguments to the functions involved. The signature of `(:)` would be a good place to start.

Comment: It produces an infinite list, but it doesn't necessarily produce an infinite loop. `take 5 $ g 3 [] [] == [3,3,3,3,3]`.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond  What would be a possible input for this function? If I use empty lists it runs infinitely. If I use something like `g 4 [1,2] [4,5]` it gives error.

Comment: @cs_student The second and third arguments have different types (in my example, `[]` is the empty list of *any* list type). Note that `z` is used both as the first and last arguments of `(:)`, which implies that if `x :: a`, then `z :: [a]` and `y :: [[a]]`. And that, really, ends up being the answer.

Comment: As to what it *does*? Not a whole lot. It builds a list whose first element is `x` and recurses with the same value of `x`. It never does anything with `y` or `z` except build new `y` and `z` arguments, so their only contribution to this function is to consume memory with unneeded thunks.

Comment: @Redu The title specifically asks how to derive the type *without* having GHCi do it for you.

Comment: @chepner you say that I can use list of any type. So why I get errors if I input something like `g 1 [a,b] [c,d]`. I understand that I need to provide 3 arguments as input, right?

Comment: You can't use *any* list of any type; `[]` is special in that it's the polymorphic value representing the empty list of any type. `g 1 [[1,2], [3,4]] [5,6]` is legal, though. That is, whatever `x` is, `z` has to be list of that type, and `y` has to be a list of lists of that type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the type. This will be short version, as it's not too complicated.

In any exercise like this, you start by assuming values have unknown types. We'll start with `x`, which we assume has some type `a`. Now, where does `x` get used? One place is with `(:)` and `z`. Since we know `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`, we can conclude that `z :: [a]`. Using the same logic, we can conclude that `y :: [[a]]`.

And with that, we know the types of all the arguments, so we know that `g :: a -> [[a]] -> [a] -> ?`. But what's the return type of `g`?

Well, now we see that `g` only gets used as the second argument of `++`, and since we know `x :: a`, then `g` must provide a value of type `[a]` to work with the value `[x] :: [a]`.

---

What does the function *do*? Not a whole lot. It builds a list whose first element is `x`, but the recursive call doesn't change the value of `x`, and further, `y` and `z` are only used to create *new* `y` and `z` arguments. They don't contribute anything to the return value; they only use up memory by contributing to unevaluated thunks.

In the end, the entire function is just a complicated way of writing `repeat`: you ignore your initial values of `y` and `z`, and build up an infinite list of `x`s.

```
> take 10 $ g 3 [] []
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
> take 10 $ g 3 [[7]] [4,5,6]
[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
```